# How do I specify additional Info for my Selector gestureRecoqnizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecoqnizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTaped:)];
[ImageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecoqnizer];
```

The only parameter sent to imageTaped is the sender.

I want to send something else, say the ImageView itself or some other object.

How do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sender.view will be your ImageView. If you want another object then add it to your ImageView Class.

```
ImageView *imageview = (ImageView*)sender.view;
NSLog(@"%@", imageview.someObject);
```

**Edit**

Here are the possible solutions I can think of.

1. Subclass `UIImageView` to have a `@property` for an object as explained above.
2. Set a tag on the UIImageView and use `sender.view.tag` and have some way to associate the tag with an object.

Basically your ImageView needs to have some sort of information to connect you to your object.

Comment: Is there no other way? For example in order for imageView to have an arbitrary someObject property we need associated object or something.

Comment: Good. I forget that you can subclass instead of just making category.